# bash script written in windows won't run properly, but will if written in linux

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a script I've been working on for installing arch Linux. I have been testing the script in a VM running in windows. when I have been testing parts in the VM and been writing it in windows. the applications I have been using is Notepadd++ in windows and vim on the Linux VM. The part that fails is the for loop in the beginning everything else runs as intended. if i write the for loop in linux it woks. If I write it in windows and copy it over(via github), that part gets skipped like it was never there but I can see it is I look at it in vim. writing it in windows has been the main way I've been writing the script so I really don't know why only this part is having issues.

[Link to script on github](https://github.com/Termanater13/archinstall/blob/master/install.sh)

part that is not working right

```
ARGCASE="CHECK"
VMINSTALL="FALSE"
RSAUPASS="FALSE"
for arg in "$@"
do
    case $ARGMODE in
        CHECK)
            case $arg in
                -u | --username)
                ARGMODE="USERNAME"
                ;;
                -p | --userpass | --userpassword)
                ARGMODE="USERPASS"
                ;;
                -r | --rootpass | --rootpassword)
                ARGMODE="ROOTPASS"
                ;;
                -vm)
                VMINSTALL="TRUE"
                ;;
                -h | --help | *)
                echo "This Script is for automating the install of arch linux"
                echo "-u\t--username\n\tSet the user name of the users account"
                echo "-p\t--userpass\t--userpassword\n\tSet the user password of the users account"
                echo "-r\t--rootpass\t--rootpassword\n\tSet the root user's password"
                echo "-vm\n\tThis is for when instaling to a virtual machine as some items are not needed since host machene takes care of them"
                echo "-rsau\n\tSet Root user password to be the same as user\n\tNOTE: This is not recomended as this could be a security risk"
                echo "-h\t--help\n\tshow this text"
                exit 0
                ;;
            esac
            ;;
        USERNAME)
            USERNAME=$arg
            ;;
        USERPASS)
            USERPASS=$arg
            ;;
        ROOTPASS)
            ROOTPASS=$arg
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: did you try running `diff` to compare the vim-version and the notepad++-version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First variable is listed as `ARGCASE` while all other references is listed as `ARGMODE`. Not using the right variable caused a loop that will not do anything as `ARGMODE` has nothing and `ARGCASE` has the appropriate value to get the case to work as intended.

Comment: found this while rewriting the file in order to get it to work. posted the answer like i did so other having similar issues should look at variable names instead of assuming it was something else like I did. fixing that one variable fixed the issue. All issued with the code you do not have to follow the link to see as its in the code block provided.

Answer (score 0):

Using a windows computer to compose a bash script can lead to encoding problems.

If you choose to use windows text editors and then transfer that document to a Unix machine such as Linux you must change the encoding.

There is a built in tool called dos2unix for this.

Run dos2unix then try again.

Comment: that does not fix the issue. that is what i originally thought it was.

Comment: When you upload it to github its from notpad++ then you clone it to linux run dos2unix  that's does'nt fix the problem ? Interesting how it works when written in linux. i was going to say the way you have nested case inside of case inside of a for loop to what i assume is to parse input arguments is written wrong. However the fact that it works when written in linux is throwing me off. Sorry i was'nt able to help but if the scripts working this must just be a curious question.

Comment: I have a picture i used to recreate the code in notepad++ since getting it off the VM is kinda hard at the moment. the only thing I can think its down to how notepad++ save the file vs how vim save the file. I might have to install git and rewrite it from scratch in vim to get it working.

Comment: This worked for me on a bash script I wrote in Windows and tried to execute in WSL, couldn't figure out what was going on, and then it dawned on me...